# Coverting Set<E> to String[] gives the elements in the wrong order

Tags: java

I'have simple POJO class as

```
public class Option {
    String optionText;

    public String getOptionText() {
        return optionText;
    }

    public void setOptionText(String optionText) {
        this.optionText = optionText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return optionText;
    }

}
```

and there I'm creating a Set object and want to convert that object to String[], I've my logic as

```
public class Main {
    Set<Option> options = new HashSet<Option>();
    public Main() {
        Option option1 = new Option();
        option1.setOptionText("Option 1");      
        options.add(option1);
        Option option2 = new Option();
        option2.setOptionText("Option 2");      
        options.add(option2);
        Option option3 = new Option();
        option3.setOptionText("Option 3");      
        options.add(option3);
        Option option4 = new Option();
        option4.setOptionText("Option 4");      
        options.add(option4);

        System.out.println("Set<Option> size is " + options.size());


        System.out.println(getCorrectAnswer(options, "a"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }


    public String getCorrectAnswer(Set<Option> options, String selectedOptionAsCorrect) {
        String answerString = null;
        String[] listOfOptions = new String[4];
        int i = 0;
        for (Option option : options) {
            listOfOptions[i] = option.getOptionText();
            System.out.println("At index " + i + " is " + option.getOptionText());
            i++;
        }
        if(selectedOptionAsCorrect.equals("a")){
            answerString = listOfOptions[0];
        }
        else if(selectedOptionAsCorrect.equals("b")){
            answerString = listOfOptions[1];
        }
        else if(selectedOptionAsCorrect.equals("c")){
            answerString = listOfOptions[2];
        }
        else if(selectedOptionAsCorrect.equals("d")){
            answerString = listOfOptions[3];
        }

        System.out.println("Answer is " + answerString);

        return answerString;        

    }

}
```

at this point I want to get out put on the console as

```
Set<Option> size is 4
At index 0 is Option 1
At index 1 is Option 2
At index 2 is Option 3
At index 3 is Option 4
Answer is Option 1
Option 1
```

means as I'm adding `Option 1`, `Option 2`,`Option 3`,`Option 4` in sequence I want to copy those Strings to String[] in same order as

`listOfOptions[0]` should contian  `Option 1`
`listOfOptions[1]` should contian  `Option 2`
`listOfOptions[2]` should contian  `Option 3`
`listOfOptions[3]` should contian  `Option 4`

but I'm getting output as

```
Set<Option> size is 4
At index 0 is Option 3
At index 1 is Option 1
At index 2 is Option 2
At index 3 is Option 4
Answer is Option 3
Option 3
```

I want to ask why 
`listOfOptions[0]` do contian  `Option 3`
that should contain `Option 1`, how to fix this are there isn't any solution or what is the logic behind the scenes can any one explain please.
t

A *ton* of thanks in advance

Comment: want to ask why  `listOfOptions[0]` do contian  `Option 3` that should contain `Option 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `LinkedHashSet<>` implementation instead of `HashSet<>`/`TreeSet<>` if you want to get elements in the same order in which they had been added.

```
Set<Option> options = new LinkedHashSet<>();
...
options.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
// prints all elements in the order which you'll expect
```

Read more at [Oracle Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html). Also I together with [Willy du Preez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4413603/willy-du-preez) suggest you looking at [lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html). In your case, they may have a place to exist.

Comment: Any difference in `HashSet<>` & `LinkedHashSet<>`

Comment: @LogicalError would you expect there *not* to be a difference when they are two separate classes?

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm newbie to this kind of stuff and your answer works good but can not accept at this time getting error of _You can not accept in xx mins_ wanna ask what is difference between those two?

Comment: @LogicalError you should read the Javadoc for the two classes, the specific behaviours are described there (I quote the differences with respect to iteration order in my answer).

Comment: Based on the use case, would suggest you look at a List instead of a Set as well.

Answer (score 4):

See the [Javadoc of `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set

If you want the iteration order to be the insertion order, you can use [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)

Answer (score 4):

From the HashSet [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

You can use a List instead of a Set since it looks like you want it to be an ordered sequence. The List [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

> An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.

You can use ArrayList as the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your time but my need is Set<E> you know __up vote for you there__